# How to get last executed JS functions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on a large and old project that run tons to JavaScript and sometimes when solving a bug its a bit hard to know which function has executed.

Is there a way to get a list of the last executed functions in Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594908/is-there-a-js-debugger-that-will-quickly-step-through-a-program-and-list-the-fun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options for resolving this issue:

- You should use ***Profiler*** in ***Chrome Develper Tools***:

  - Step 1:
    [image]
  - Step 2
    [image]

So you can see list functions which was executed while profiling.

- Also you can use ***PageSpeed Insights for Google Chrome*** extension ([link](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights_extensions))

Comment: Thanks, the PageSpeed seems a useful tool, but for the current purpouse the profiler was enough (although it does not show the functions in the call order but by usage).